# ItemArray.checklist.add() not appending string to ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

i have been learning java for around 3 days now but i cannot seem to append data to one of my ArrayLists (checklist). The output when attempting to show all items inside the array is always []. Help would be greatly Appreciated!

ShopAssist.java:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

    class ShopAssist {
        public static void main(String[] args){
            //Items itemchecklist = new Items();
            System.out.println("( Add | Remove | Show | Exit )");
            System.out.print(">");
            Scanner menuinput = new Scanner(System.in);
            String choice = menuinput.nextLine();
            if (choice.equals("Add")){
                AddItem();
            }

            else if (choice.equals("Remove")){
                RemoveItem();
            }
            else if (choice.equals("Show")){
                ShowItems();
            }

        while(true){
            main(null);
        }
        }

        public static void AddItem(){
            Items ItemArray = new Items();
            System.out.print("Add: ");
            Scanner addinput = new Scanner(System.in);
            String addchoice = addinput.nextLine();
            ItemArray.checklist.add(addchoice);
            System.out.println("Info: " + addchoice + " has been added to checklist!");
        }

        public static void RemoveItem(){
            System.out.println("RemoveItem Method");
        }

        public static void ShowItems(){
            Items ItemArray = new Items();
            System.out.println("ShowItems Method");
            System.out.println(ItemArray.checklist);
        }
    }
```

Items.java:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Items {
    ArrayList<String> checklist = new ArrayList<String>();

}
```

Comment: What does this line print out? `System.out.println("Info: " + addchoice + " has been added to checklist!");`

Comment: You have a new array in each method so it will always just show []. just create one globally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You create multiple instances of  `ItemArray`.
Both in `AddItem()` and `ShowItems()`.
So you never use the same instance in these methods.

It should be written once :

```
 Items ItemArray = new Items();
```

and be either a passed parameter to these methods or a field of the class.

And ideally, this should be a `private` instance field and you should change your `static` methods into instance methods :

```
class ShopAssist {

    private Items items = new Items();
    ...

    public static void main(String[] args){

      ShopAssist shopAssist = new ShopAssist();

      while (true) {
        System.out.println("( Add | Remove | Show | Exit )");
        System.out.print(">");
        Scanner menuinput = new Scanner(System.in);
        String choice = menuinput.nextLine();

        if (choice.equals("Add")) {
          shopAssist.addItem();
        } 
        else if (choice.equals("Remove")) {
          shopAssist.removeItem();
        } 
        else if (choice.equals("Show")) {
          shopAssist.showItems();
        }
      }
    }

    public void addItem(){
        ...
    }
    ...
    public void showItems(){          
        System.out.println("ShowItems Method");
        System.out.println(items.checklist);
    }
    ...
}
```

Using `static` everywhere is not OOP.

Comment: Where do i place "private Items items = new Items();"

Comment: As a declared field as in the example. I updated to be more exhaustive.

Comment: Yes, but the array is still empty after adding something to it

Comment: It is because of the  `while (true) {` that invokes `main()` at each user action. As workaround, you can surround the code in a `while (true)`. I updated